# Getting the name of the building I am in

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using google places API to retrieve of the place I am at.  The only problem is that google places doesn't tell me what building I am in but the building I am near by.  I set it to send me a list in order from nearest places to farthest places.  Then I ran into another problem.  If I am standing/sitting at the end of the building, it will give me the building next to the one I am in.
[image]

Okay X represents where I am standing.  The red circles represents where google thinks the buildings are at.  Lets say I requested to see where I am.  Google will then tell me I am at the grey building because I am closer to the grey's building red circle than my building's red circle.  I just cannot think of away around this or to get this to give me the write building.  Any creative suggestions?

I WILL GIVE 100 POINTS TO THE ONE THAT GETS IT WORKING!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could modifiate the google places by setting your own map by defining each buildings wall, but I think there is for now no chance (you can still do it, but it would take enormous time!).

You can maybe change the main view of the app from "In what building I'm" to "What is the nearest building".
As I never used google plans, it's possible that there are other ways to fix it!

Hope I helped you abit :)

Comment: I thought about the border thing but that's impossible since I will have to do that for every building there is.  Fortunately, I need to know where I am at.  Let's say I am at a college campus, I want my app to know I go to that college.

Comment: you can maybe do that your app localates you when you are at the campus around 50 meters radius. Maybe you're not in the campus, but you'll probably be in front of it or behind and can see it.

Comment: That wouldn't work either cause I want it to locate me where ever I am but what I can do is find the places near by and and give each place a radius based on what kind of building it is.  Lets say if it is a college campus I would give it a radius of 200 meters or if its is just like a small store a radius of 20 meters than I can find where I am.  I will give this a try and let you know! Thank You!

Comment: Hope you'll get it! I know how it's frustrating to search a solution to something impossibly possible ;)